# Unique elements of a list and corresponding indices

Tags: haskell, unique

Given a list `vs`, I want to get the list `vs'` of the unique elements of `vs`, as well as the indices of the elements of `vs` in `vs'`. For example, if `vs = [7, 8, 7, 8, 9]` I want to get `[7,8,9]` (the unique elements) and `[0,1,0,1,2]` (the indices).

An easy implementation is:

```
import           Data.List
import           Data.Maybe

unique :: Eq a => [a] -> ([a], [Int])
unique vs = (vsnub, indices)
  where
  vsnub = nub vs
  indices = map (\v -> fromJust $ elemIndex v vsnub) vs
```

Is there a more efficient option?

I've done an implementation of the following pseudo-code (saying that `vs` is a list of numbers) with the help of mutable vectors, but this is slow:

```
n = length of vs
idx = list of n integers (to store the indices)
visited = [false, false, ..., false] (n elements)
nvs = list of n numbers (to store the unique elements)
count = 0 
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  if(not visited[i])
  {
    nvs[count] = vs[i]
    idx[i] = count
    visited[i] = true
    for(j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
    {
      if(vs[j] = vs[i])
      {
        visited[j] = true
        idx[j] = count
      }
    }
    count ++
  }
}
nvs = first 'count' elements of nvs
```

## EDIT

Here is my code using mutable vectors (slow):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import           Control.Monad               ((>>=))
import           Data.Vector.Unboxed         (Unbox, Vector, freeze, (!))
import           Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable (IOVector, new, write)
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as VM

unique' :: forall a . (Unbox a, Eq a) => [a] -> IO (Vector a, Vector Int)
unique' vs = do
  let n = length vs
  idx <- VM.replicate n 0 :: IO (IOVector Int)
  visited <- VM.replicate n False :: IO (IOVector Bool)
  nvs <- new n :: IO (IOVector a)
  let inner :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
      inner i j count | j == n = return ()
                      | otherwise =
                        if vs !! i == vs !! j
                          then do
                            write visited j True
                            write idx j count
                            inner i (j+1) count
                          else inner i (j+1) count
  let go :: Int -> Int -> IO (IOVector a)
      go i count | i == n = return $ VM.take count nvs
                 | otherwise = do
                   vst <- VM.read visited i
                   if not vst
                     then do
                       write nvs count (vs !! i)
                       write idx i count
                       write visited i True
                       _ <- inner i (i+1) count
                       go (i+1) (count + 1)
                     else go (i+1) count
  nvs' <- go 0 0 >>= freeze
  idx' <- freeze idx
  return (nvs', idx')
```

Comment: (1) Would strengthening the constraint from `Eq` to `Ord` be a problem? If it wouldn't, you might find use in  `Ord`-exploiting nub functions like [these ones](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Containers-ListUtils.html). (2) I suggest adding your mutable vector implementation, in case you want folks to have a look at it.

Comment: @duplode Code added. In my situation, `vs` is a list of triplets of doubles, so I think `Ord` is nice. I take a look at your link, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's helpful for things like these to focus on what state you actually need to maintain, and then encode that as an extra parameter to your recursive function. For this case, you need:

- The elements you've seen so far (and their positions).
- The position in the output list you're at.

The first of those can be encapsulated with `Map`, and the second with an `Int`.

```hs
uniqInds :: Ord a => [a] -> ([a], [Int])
uniqInds = go 0 Map.empty
  where
    go i m [] = ([],[])
    go i m (x:xs) = case Map.insertLookupWithKey (\_ _ j -> j) x i m of
        (Nothing, m') -> first (x:) (second (i:) (go (i+1) m' xs))
        (Just j , m') ->             second (j:) (go i     m' xs)
```

`Map.insertLookupWithKey` is a function that lets us do the lookup and alter at the same time. `first` and `second` map a function over the first and second elements in a tuple, respectively. You can actually rewrite this function as a fold:

```hs
uniqInds :: Ord a => [a] -> ([a], [Int])
uniqInds xs = foldr f (\_ _ -> ([],[])) xs 0 Map.empty
  where
    f x xs i m = case Map.insertLookupWithKey (\_ _ j -> j) x i m of
        (Nothing, m') -> first (x:) (second (i:) (xs (i+1) m'))
        (Just j , m') ->             second (j:) (xs i     m')
```

Comment: This is probably better than any `nubOrd` solution (cf. [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55775412/unique-elements-of-a-list-and-corresponding-indices?noredirect=1#comment98223337_55775412)), as it only does a single pass through the input list, and therefore doesn't require holding it in memory.

Comment: Or `bimap (x:) (i:)`, which you can get from `Data.Bifunctor` along with `first` and `second`.

Comment: As for `insertLookupWithKey` ... that's a mess of a function. I think it's better to guide people toward the more general `alterF` interface.

Comment: Thank you, it works well. Could you explain why the `Ord` constraint is needed? I don't see.

Comment: Oh I see this is required for the keys of the map.

Answer (score 3):

This is a variation of oisdk's solution that uses `alterF` instead of the older, less powerful, and stranger `insertLookupWithKey`.

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import Data.Bifunctor

uniqInds :: Ord a => [a] -> ([a], [Int])
uniqInds = go 0 M.empty
  where
    go i m [] = ([],[])
    go i m (x:xs) = case M.alterF chg x m of
       Right m' -> bimap (x:) (i:) (go (i+1) m' xs)
       Left j -> second (j:) (go i m xs)
      where
        -- The value wasn't found. Insert its index.
        chg Nothing = Right (Just i)
        -- The value was found. Return its index.
        chg (Just j) = Left j
```

This uses `alterF` with the `Either Int` functor. At each step, you *either* get the stored index *or* you get a new map.

Comment: Thank you,this is instructive. I have benchmarked and it seems that oisdk's solution is slightly faster (really slightly). But I have not tested many situations.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, it's not surprising that would sometimes be the case. But at what point do clarity and the mental cost of learning a bunch of specialized functions overtake performance?